# Firebase Realtime Database: Is it safe to listen massive value events in the same time?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to build a Firebase Realtime Database with like this structure:

```
root -+- profile -+- user 1
      |           +- user 2
      |           +- user 3
      |           +- user 4
      ...
      +- somestuff -+- user 1
      |             +- user 2
      |             +- user 3
      |             +- user 4
      ...
```

I want to make a phone client subscribe `/profile/user1`, `/profile/user2`... and as many as it needs.

My question is, if the amount becomes hundreds or thousands, is it still safe to register a value event listener for each path? Will the SDK (Android and iOS) handle this gracefully, or it will try to open that many websockets so I can't struct data in this way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase will funnel all traffic over a single (web) socket. So there is no penalty in the number of sockets being opened.

That said: your users will have the best experience if you app only synchronizes data that it is displays on the screen. If you find yourself with hundreds of active listeners, you're probably downloading more data than is currently on the screen.

Comment: Do you mean it's better to sync data only when it will be used, rather than listening their change in background?

Comment: If you're not going to show the data to the user, I wouldn't download it. There may be exceptions to this, but in general: only download what you're "immediately" going to show to the user.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, may I ask you to have a look at 'EDIT2' of this Firebase related question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41873387/firebase-web-update-database-where-a-certain-value-is-found?answertab=active#tab-top ?