# firebase web - update database where a certain value is found

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, updates

My database looks as below :

[image]

I need to update the `division_name` where the `index_num` is 3.
I tried the following code but it did not work -

```
    var division_index_found="3";
    var division_name_given="new div";

    var query_update=firebase.database().ref("/divisions")
    .orderByChild('index_num').equalTo(division_index_found);

    query_update.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.ref.update({ division_name: division_name_given });
    });
```

What approach to adopt here ?

**EDIT1:**
  I get warning in chrome console :

FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "index_num" at /divisions to your security rules for better performance

**EDIT2:**
From the firebase database the `districts` node (?) looks like :

```
 "districts" : {
    "-KbVYCSO8wrMoXD3vL81" : {
      "district_name" : "Rangpur",
      "division_index" : "3",
      "index_num" : 2
    },
    "-KbVYHgbWMDMtGsnmvei" : {
      "district_name" : "jessore",
      "division_index" : "3",
      "index_num" : 3
    },
    "-KbVYKtSnPMFDkx9z0cU" : {
      "district_name" : "district 1",
      "division_index" : "3",
      "index_num" : 4
    }
  }
```

Now I want to update `district_name` for a certain `index_num` and `division_index`. I use the following code :

```
var district_index="3";
var division_index="3"
var district_index_parsed = parseInt(district_index);

var query_update=firebase.database().ref("/districts")
.orderByChild('index_num').equalTo(district_index_parsed);


 query_update.once("child_added", function(snapshot) {

 snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot_indiv){

        if(parseInt(snapshot_indiv.division_index)==parseInt(division_index)){


    var district_name_again="new district name";        

snapshot_indiv.ref.update({ district_name: district_name_again },function(error){

});

}// end of if division_index compare
    });// end of forEach



});// end of query_update once
```

But the console shows :

```
Uncaught Error: No index defined for index_num

at je.get (firebase-database.js:94)
...
...
 at edit_districts.php:359
...
```

which ultimately hints at the following line of code in my `edit_districts.php` file:

```
snapshot.forEach(function(snapshot_indiv){
```

inside the `query_update.once` part.The `forEach` method seems to make the problem.

And the security rules are defined as

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",

    "divisions": {
      ".indexOn": "index_num"
    },

      "districts": {
      ".indexOn": "index_num"
    },

  }
}
```

**How to get rid of the error to update the database ?**

Comment: What do you mean "it does not work?" What happens?

Comment: @martinjakubik, no change found in database

Comment: @martinjakubik, 'EDIT1' added in OP

Comment: That warning tells you exactly what to do (search for it if you need help). But the operation should work even with that warning.

Comment: A quick guess is that you're storing the index as a number, but are comparing to a string. (it's hard to be sure in the screenshot, next time please share the JSON as text - which you can get by clicking the Export JSON link in your Firebase Database console)  If that's indeed the case: `firebase.database().ref("/divisions")
    .orderByChild('index_num').equalTo(3)` (without quotes)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, have been googling so far but in vain. And the operation still does not work.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, yes , discarding the quotes works. But why should it be `integer` instead of `string` ?

Comment: Because you stored the index in your database as a number. In JavaScript `3 !== "3"`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, oh I see. And how to remove the warning i.e. add the suggested security rule? Answer instead of comment would be great.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, added 'EDIT2'

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add an index to your Firebase Database security rules. I recommend reading the [Firebase documentation on security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), specifically the [section on indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data).

From the documentation comes this first sample:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "dinosaurs": {
      ".indexOn": ["height", "length"]
    }
  }
}
```

Modified to your data structure, it'll look something like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "divisions": {
      ".indexOn": "index_num"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: include the solution to use number instead of string for comparison so that it becomes a full answer.

Comment: How to add the rule - through  manual edit of the rules under 'rules' section ?

Comment: Take a look at 'EDIT2', new prob pops up.